# PyTorch: Slightly different results for different batch sizes

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I am using a VGG19 network to classify CIFAR10 images, yet I have slightly different results for data of different batch sizes. Code:

```
net.eval()

f_image = net.forward(Variable(image, requires_grad=True)).data

f_image2 = net.forward(Variable(image[0].unsqueeze(0), requires_grad=True)).data

f_image3 = net.forward(Variable(image[0].unsqueeze(0), requires_grad=True)).data

print(‘f_image - f_image2 = {}’.format((f_image[0] - f_image2).cpu().data.numpy()))
print(‘f_image - f_image3 = {}’.format((f_image[0] - f_image3).cpu().data.numpy()))
print(‘f_image2 - f_image3 = {}’.format((f_image2 - f_image3).cpu().data.numpy()))
```

Specifically, image is of size `[batch_size, n_channels, height, width]`. And I expect `f_image[0].unsqueeze(0)` to be the same as `f_image2` and `f_image3`. However, they are slightly different:

```
f_image - f_image2 = [[ 0.0000000e+00 3.7252903e-09 -1.8626451e-09 3.7252903e-09
0.0000000e+00 -3.7252903e-09 3.7252903e-09 -1.8626451e-09
3.7252903e-09 -1.3969839e-09]]
f_image - f_image3 = [[ 0.0000000e+00 3.7252903e-09 -1.8626451e-09 3.7252903e-09
0.0000000e+00 -3.7252903e-09 3.7252903e-09 -1.8626451e-09
3.7252903e-09 -1.3969839e-09]]
f_image2 - f_image3 = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The difference is very small, is it a bug or expected behavior of PyTorch?

Comment: is your net in eval mode?

Comment: @shai Yes, in eval mode.

Comment: I observed the same problem with AlexNet, even the same 3.7252903e-09 in most positions

Comment: @DavidNg I am actually wondering if this is caused by limited precision of float32